# Train multiple labels for same instance detected with object Detection Tensorflow API

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection-api, multilabel-classification

I would like to know how can I train a model to detect an instance and give it multiple labels at the same time.

I am working on a project which detects nespresso capsules and classify them. I have already create a model which detects the capsule and classify it to Original or Vertuo and now I want it to classify it according to their names ( sometimes Vertuo and original have the same name it's just the shape that is different ). I have used Tensorflow API for detecting objects with the pre-trained model faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1. I want the model to detect the object and classify it for example to original and caprricio.
[here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qrZh.png)